# tikz foreach loop alignment failure

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, foreach

```
 \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

 \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[t]
 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.2em]

 \node (T0) at (0,0) {$T_{0}$};
  \node (T1) [below= of T0] {$T_{1}$};
  \foreach \x in {2,3,...,8} {
     \pgfmathsetmacro\result{\x-1}
     \node (T\x) [below=of T\result] {$T_{\x}$};
   }
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}
  \end{document}
```

Hi! In the above code I create 9 nodes. The first two which are out of the loop are perfectly aligned. The rest are not. Can someone suggest a solution so that all nodes are aligned? (Except for the obvious solution of copying and pasting).

I think the problem is in the *positioning* library because if I use `\node (T\x.0) [below of = T\result] {$T_{\x}$};` instead then it appears correctly but I will have to adjust all node distances of by hand. The diagram includes many more nodes which I am not including for terms of simplicity.
Below you can see the result of the code.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, if I understand your problem correctly, but nodes can be arranged in vertical line by aligned to center of nodes by:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.2em]
    \node (T0) at (0,0) {$T_{0}$};
\foreach[count=\xi from 0]  \x in {1,2,...,8} 
     \node[below=of T\xi] (T\x)  {$T_{\x}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` instead of `\pgfmathsetmacro`. The problem is that `\pgfmathsetmacro` sets the macro to be a float; `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` truncates that to an integer.

On a side note, if you load `tikz` it is not necessary to explicitly load `pgf`, and moreover, for the standalone class, the `[tikz]` option means you don't have to load TikZ.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

 \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.2em]

 \node (T0) at (0,0) {$T_{0}$};
  \node (T1) [below= of T0] {$T_{1}$};
  \foreach \x in {2,3,...,8} {
     \pgfmathtruncatemacro\result{\x-1}
     \node (T\x) [below=of T\result] {$T_{\x}$};
   }
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @orestis: Zarko's answer is better IMHO. I will not be offended if you give the "accept" to him/her :-)